# React - unit testing with a setup function

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I have the following case:

```
describe('API - Input component', () => {
   describe('Input element', () => {
    it('should have a modifier to its class if data entered is erroneous', () => {
      const wrapper = shallow(<Input error="Invalid data" />);

      expect(wrapper.find('input').props().className).toBe('form-field__input form-field__input--error');
    });
  });
});
```

This works perfectly fine. As long as I pass some data to my **error** props a modifier class should be expected and the test passes.

Now, I want to achieve the same thing but using a setup function. Like this:

```
function setup () {
  const props = {
    error: {}
  };

  return shallow(<Input {...props} />);
}

describe('API - Input component', () => {
   describe('Input element', () => {
    it('should have a modifier to its class if data entered is erroneous', () => {
      const wrapper = setup(how do I pass my props here?!);

      expect(wrapper.find('input').props().className).toBe('form-field__input form-field__input--error');
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> const wrapper = setup(how do I pass my props here?!);

and the answer simply is the props itself as **Literal Object** `{prop1: value1, prop2: value2 ,... , propN: valueN}` :

```
  const wrapper = setup({error: 'Invalid data'});
```

Know that assuming `setup` should be :

```
function setup (props) {
  return shallow(<Input {...props} />);
}
```

If you want default props in setup , use `Object.assign` to extend the default props in setup with the props of arguments.

```
function setup (props) {
  const defaultPropsOfSetup = {
    error : 'Invalid error'
  };
  props = Object.assign(defaultPropsOfSetup, props); 
  return shallow(<Input {...props} />);
}
```

Comment: Welcome    